# Disable Thunderbird "failed to connect" notifications

Tags: thunderbird

My network manager doesn't start until I log in, so for the first ten seconds or so after I login I have no Internet connection. The problem is that I have Thunderbird set to automatically start on login, so it helpfully tells me it "failed to connect" *every time I log in*. Also, my Internet connection isn't too reliable, so I sometimes get those messages even when I'm supposedly connected. Is there any way to disable these notifications, while still allowing the ones about new mail?

**Computer info:**

Thunderbird 15.0

```
$ uname -a
Linux [HOSTNAME REDACTED] 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Probably irrelevant:**

NetworkManager Version 0.9.0.1 (nm09 20120407)

KDE Platform Version 4.8.4 (4.8.4)